# Visual Studio 2015 IOS Remote build (VCRemote on IOS) fails with Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open

Tags: c++, ios, node.js, macos

I am getting started with C++ cross platform building in VS 2015.
The Android projects build and run correctly.

I am currently attempting to build one of the IOS example projects provided with VS2015. Specifically OpenGLESApp1 but all projects have the same problem.

My Environments:
Windows 10 PC with Visual Studio 2015 Community Version 14.0.25425.01 Update 3
Configured for multi platform and connected to:
Mac OSX Yosemite running vcremote v1.0.8 in either secure or unsecure 'vcremote --secure false' with Node.js v4.4.7-2, npm v2.15.8

I have been through all the VS2015 help pages on this where no one else seems to have this problem.

Also please note that the Android projects compile and run correctly.

The problem:
I am unable to build any of the example projects and have been trying for days now.
They fail with the following error in vcremote on the Mac:

> Unzipping project payload /var/folders/mt/c9hysrdd3w1cfprks2ylkshc0000gn/T/tmp-943cpkcn0f7Oo7t.zip to /Users/Terry/vcremote.
> ****** Server will shutdown due to uncaught error ******
> { [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open ...

The project fails with no changes made by myself. I build from the root of drive S: to keep the path sizes small, just in case.

I can find the zip file in my temp folder on the PC so I know it exists.

Here is the output from vcremote:

> Poiuys-Mac-mini:~ Terry$ vcremote
>
> vcremote
> Copyright (C) 2014 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
> 1.0.8
>
> VC build library initialized.
>
> Remote build server listening on [https] port 3030
>
> GET /projects/devices/?ver=1.4.0 200 400ms - 1.53kb
>
> GET /projects?ver=1.4.0 200 5ms - 348b
>
> Adding new project in the collection.
>
> Uploading project 6a650a03-95e9-4ab1-8d5c-5dd80ac6d3e9 to /Users/Terry/vcremote.
>
> Added new project in the collection, project id: 6a650a03-95e9-4ab1-8d5c-5dd80ac6d3e9, project directory: /Users/Terry/vcremote
>
> POST /projects?ver=1.4.0&loc=%2fUsers%2fTerry%2fvcremote&payload=false 200 4ms - 589b
>
> Uploading project 20b88568-f682-418b-adc2-1ef2b58b8bf6 to /Users/Terry/vcremote.
>
> Uploading payload to /var/folders/mt/c9hysrdd3w1cfprks2ylkshc0000gn/T/tmp-943cpkcn0f7Oo7t.zip.
>
> Finished uploading payload.
>
> Unzipping project payload /var/folders/mt/c9hysrdd3w1cfprks2ylkshc0000gn/T/tmp-943cpkcn0f7Oo7t.zip to /Users/Terry/vcremote.
>
> ****** Server will shutdown due to uncaught error ******
>
> { [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/folders/mt/c9hysrdd3w1cfprks2ylkshc0000gn/T/tmp-943cpkcn0f7Oo7t.zip']
>
> errno: -2,
>
> code: 'ENOENT',
>
> syscall: 'open',
>
> path: '/var/folders/mt/c9hysrdd3w1cfprks2ylkshc0000gn/T/tmp-943cpkcn0f7Oo7t.zip' }
>
> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/folders/mt/c9hysrdd3w1cfprks2ylkshc0000gn/T/tmp-943cpkcn0f7Oo7t.zip'
>
> ```
> at Error (native)
> ```
>
> ****** Performing server shutdown procedures.

The VS output is available if required but is very long.

Has anyone any experience with C++ remote building on IOS from a PC?

Any help or hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you ever figured out what the problem is? I'm trying to do the same thing. In my case it actually compiles but debugging does not work at all. When launching the debugger a simulator on the paired Mac gets started but the app is not launched. Even if I manually deploy the built app to the simulator and start it Visual Studio just does nothing.

Comment: No I'm afraid I had to give up on remote build on IOS, simply couldn't get it working. - will be looking into VS 2017 at some point to see if things have improved.

Comment: they haven't. In 2017